# d3 click handler not working on leaflet map layer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

Good evening.

I've added a series of d3 points to a leaflet map, and then wanted to use click handlers on those points to drive another panel. But I don't seem to be able to get the handler to pick up. Why?

You can see the file so far:
http://jsbin.com/bewudenide/edit?html,output

The code that generates the circle points on a custom layer on leaflet.js:

```
var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(collection)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "black")  
            .style("opacity", .6) 
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("r", 10);
```

I thought it would be simple case of adding click handlers for the mouseover and click events thus:

```
feature.on("click", click);
    function click(d) {
        console.log(d.name); 
     }
```

And:

```
feature.on("mouseover", mouse_over);
function mouse_over(d) {
    d3.select(this) 
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("background", "lightBlue")
        .style("color", "white");
      }
```

While the click function registers to console, I'm not clear why the mouse_over function doesn't change the style of the point. I was also expecting to see the pointer to change, but it doesn't.

Please excuse my lack of experience with d3, javascript or leaflet.

EDIT:

I now realise that I hadn't added some of the JSON used by the existing code. It looks like

```
[{
"index":1,"name":"Adderley Green Surgery","total":276266.2700000001},{
    "index":2,"name":"Alton Surgery","total":416559.8999999998},{
        "index":3,"name":"Apsley Surgery","total":1023757.89999999998}]
```

Comment: In your JSBin, ```collection``` is null in the ```d3.json``` handler, presumably because JSBin can't find the target JSON. It's a little difficult to diagnose further with that bug. Can you strip your code down to a smaller example of the specific, and reproducible, issue you're facing?

Comment: You need to check what are valid style attributes for svg objects. Try stroke and fill. Why do you expect the pointer to change?

Comment: @benjarwar I couldn't work out how to hard code the sample JSON into JSBIN so it would run. Instead, I've added a sample of the JSON in the question. I hope that helps?

Comment: @CoolBlue I took the style attributes from a Udacity tutorial which provided the framework for adding events. I suspect I was being naive about the pointer change - I thought it might be a natural interaction between an object when 'mouseover' was triggered.

Comment: @elksie5000, what's your point? There is no background or color styles for svg objects. No doubt the tutorial you copied the code from was talking about buttons or some other HTML object but not svg...

Comment: @CoolBlue I just wanted to explain what I'd done, that's all. You were right: the Udacity code acted on an HTML object, a point I'd not appreciated. That also explained why replacing the code with console.log did trigger.

Comment: OK, so what happens when you take that into account? Does it fix the problem?

Comment: It does. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Then, perhaps we should do the answer/accept thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the style attributes are not valid for the svg element.
Try...

```
feature.on("mouseover", mouse_over);
function mouse_over(d) {
    d3.select(this) 
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("fill", "lightBlue")
        .style("stroke", "white");
      }
```

Or...

```
feature.on("mouseover", mouse_over);
function mouse_over(d) {
    d3.select(this) 
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style({fill: "lightBlue", stroke: "white"});
      }
```

Or...

```
feature.on("mouseover", mouse_over);
function mouse_over(d) {
    d3.select(this) 
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr({fill: "lightBlue", stroke: "white"});
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using leaflet 1.0, I think the reason is that leaflet has set "pointer-event" as "none":
[Figure showing SVG within leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG5aM.png)

which makes the click event cannot be fired. So the solution is quite simple, just set "pointer-event" as "all" by using css, then it works! I have tried it by using leaflet 1.0.

pointer-events:
[pointer-events description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events)

Comment: Another related link: https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay/issues/23